# Subscribe to observable returning undefined

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a service to update a product, but subscription to it is returning undefined. Promise working fine
Here is my code
service

```
        updateProduct (id,product): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(this.product_url + 'products/' + id, product, {observe : 'response'})
        .pipe(

          catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateProduct'))
        );
      }
 private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      this.toastr.error(error); // log to console instead

      this.toastr.error(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

component

```
this.productService.updateProduct(this.myid,product).subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data)
  this.response = data
  console.log(this.response)
})
```

Comment: at which point you see the undefined?

Comment: Check the api call in network tools. It's high likely that the error is there.

Comment: Post the code for this.handleError<any>('updateProduct')

Comment: you can handle the general errors in the angular httpinterceptor instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your handleError method returns undefined and doesn't throw an error, if there was an error in the original response, you could be continuing the pipe and then your lambda would be called with data being undefined.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError

From the example in the Angular docs notice how the handleError function returns a new observable (the catchError operator will continue execution with whatever you return):

```
// Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
return of(result as T);
```

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#final-code-review

Answer (score 0):

Can you try remove the catchError operator and the pipe and see if anything comes back. Also, what does handleError do?

```
public updateProduct(id: string, product: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.product_url + 'products/' + id, product);
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with code from your handleError?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured due to handlerror method catched an error.So better use interceptors for global error handling

Answer (score -3):

I would do it like this:

```
  updateProduct (id,product): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.product_url + 'products/' + id, product);
  }
```

and handle some of the errors globaly in an interceptor. And let some error like bad request(400) localy for any form.

```
onSubmit(){
   myservice.updateProduct(...).subscribe(response=>{
    //success
   },error=>{
     //show form errors
   });
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. You cannot .pipe() a subscription

Comment: He shouldn't be subscribing in a service. That's done in a component while calling the service method.

Comment: Can anyone please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394836/7628381